# Scikit learn: RidgeCV seems not to give the best option?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, regression, cross-validation

This is my `X`:

```
 X =  np.array([[  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   5.,   4.,   0.,   2.,   5.,  11.,
              3.,  19.,   2.],
           [  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   1.,   4.,   0.,   3.,   5.,  13.,
              4.,  19.,   2.],
           [  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   4.,   4.,   0.,   3.,   5.,  12.,
              2.,  19.,   2.],
           [  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   1.,   4.,   0.,   4.,   5.,  12.,
              4.,  19.,   2.],
           [  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   1.,   4.,   0.,   3.,   5.,  12.,
              5.,  19.,   2.],
           [  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   2.,   4.,   0.,   3.,   5.,  13.,
              3.,  19.,   2.],
           [  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   2.,   4.,   0.,   4.,   5.,  11.,
              4.,  19.,   2.],
           [  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   2.,   4.,   0.,   3.,   5.,  11.,
              5.,  19.,   2.],
           [  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   1.,   4.,   0.,   3.,   5.,  12.,
              5.,  19.,   2.],
           [  5.,   8.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   1.,   4.,   0.,   3.,   5.,  12.,
              5.,  19.,   2.]])
```

and this is my response `y`

```
y = np.array([ 70.14963195,  70.20937046,  70.20890363,  70.14310389,
        70.18076206,  70.13179977,  70.13536797,  70.10700998,
        70.09194074,  70.09958111])
```

**Ridge Regression**

```
    # alpha = 0.1
    model = Ridge(alpha = 0.1)
    model.fit(X,y)
    model.score(X,y)   # gives 0.36898424479816627

    # alpha = 0.01
    model1 = Ridge(alpha = 0.01)
    model1.fit(X,y)
    model1.score(X,y)     # gives 0.3690347045143918 > 0.36898424479816627

    # alpha = 0.001
    model2 = Ridge(alpha = 0.001)
    model2.fit(X,y)
    model2.score(X,y)  #gives 0.36903522192901728 > 0.3690347045143918

    # alpha = 0.0001
    model3 = Ridge(alpha = 0.0001)
    model3.fit(X,y)
    model3.score(X,y)  # gives 0.36903522711624259 > 0.36903522192901728
```

Thus from here it should be clear that `alpha = 0.0001` is the best option. Indeed reading the documentation it says that the score is the coefficient of determination. If the coefficient closest to 1 describes the best model. Now let's see what `RidgeCV` tells us

**RidgeCV regression**

```
modelCV = RidgeCV(alphas = [0.1, 0.01, 0.001,0.0001], store_cv_values = True)
modelCV.fit(X,y)
modelCV.alpha_  #giving 0.1
modelCV.score(X,y)  # giving 0.36898424479812919 which is the same score as ridge regression with alpha = 0.1
```

What is going wrong? Surely we can check manually, as I have done, that all the other alphas are better. So not only it is not choosing the best alpha, but it is choosing the worst!

Can someone explain to me what it's going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's perfectly normal behaviour.

Your manual approach is **not doing any cross-validation** and therefore train- and testdata are the same!

```
# alpha = 0.1
model = Ridge(alpha = 0.1)
model.fit(X,y)   #!!
model.score(X,y) #!!
```

With some mild assumptions on the classifier (e.g convex-optimization problem) and the solver (guaranteed epsilon-convergence) this means, that **you will always get the lowest score for the least regularized model** (overfitting!): in your case: `alpha = 0.0001`.  (Have a look at RidgeRegression's [formula](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ridge-regression))

Using **RidgeCV** though, **cross-validation is by default activated**, *leave-one-out* being selected. The scoring-process used to determine the best parameters is not using the same data for train and test.

You can print out the mean `cv_values_` as you are using `store_cv_values = True`:

```
print(np.mean(modelCV.cv_values_, axis=0))
# [ 0.00226582  0.0022879   0.00229021  0.00229044]
# alpha [0.1, 0.01, 0.001,0.0001]
# by default: mean squared errors!
# left / 0.1 best; right / 0.0001 worst 
# this is only a demo: not sure how sklearn selects best (mean vs. ?)
```

This is expected, but not the general rule. As you are now scoring with two different datasets, you are optimizing not to overfit and with high probability some regularization is needed!

Comment: Okay so let me see if I get what you say. In `Ridge()` we use the whole `X`, so training set and testing set are the same. While in `RidgeCV()` we are doing leave-one-out cross validation so we do regression dividing the `X` such that each observation has been in the testing set exactly once?

Comment: Also, the reason why `RidgeCV()` gives `0.1` is because when doing cross validation `0.1` gives a less  flexible model than `0.0001`, since there is less complexity, and thus `0.1` does overfit less than `0.0001`?

Comment: So is this mainly a problem of overfitting the data? The smaller the value of alpha, the more we are likely to overfit?

Comment: Also, thank you a lot for your answer! I will surely mark it! Would it be possible to expand a bit more? I am very new to Machine Learning and some concepts stil mix in my mind.

Comment: Yes. Overfitting. You should never use ML in the way you did in your manual approach and you observed the reason. You only did optimize the test-error, which is always lower without regularization / penalties like alpha.

Comment: would you say that (apart from computational expenses) it would always be better to use the `CV` version of the regression models in scikit-learn?

Comment: ML without cross-validation is doomed. Maybe you should grab some ML book and work out the basics. [Also look at this nice plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)). I also think, that my answer is quite complete, given this question and i think i won't expand much. SO is probably not the right place to explain these basics / CV. **RidgeCV** is just a nice automatic-version! You can use the classic Ridge too, but combine with any of your CV-schemes. But sometimes a problem has some optimized CV, therefore these wrappers exist (e.g. warm-starting the opt-process).

Comment: thank you. I am currently studying on Introduction to Statistical Learning, however I am very fresh so I still get a lot of confusion. If you could help, I was wondering: in the last few lines you calculated the mean squared error. At the same time, `RidgeCV` outputs `R^2`. I know that `adjR^2` is better than `R^2`, so which one would be better between mean squared error and `adjR^2`?

Comment: There is no general rule. I only looked at MSE, because it's the default-output. The decision which one to trust is some model-decision with possibly different outcomes. But it's hard to generalize. And i have to say, that i never did look much into these measures.

Comment: Okay thank you! To change the default I should use the keyword argument `scoring = `?

Comment: Yes. Go through the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html).

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I found something weird. If I do `modelcv = RidgeCV(alphas = [0.1,0.01,0.001, 0.0001], scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error', store_cv_values = True)`, and fit it `modelcv.fit(x,y)` and see the score `modelcv.score(x,y)` I get `0.36898424479812919`, choosing `alpha_ = 0.1`. However if I don't specify the scoring (which should still be mean squared error by default)  and do `modelcv2 = RidgeCV(alphas = [0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001], store_cv_values = True)` and fit `modelcv2.fit(x,y)` then the score is still `0.36898424479812919` and `alpha_=0.1`

Comment: However if I then look at the `cv_scores_` and take the mean along `axis = 0` I can see that for `modelcv` we have `array([-0.00017812, -0.0001959 , -0.00019797, -0.00019818])` while for `modelcv2` we have `array([ 0.00226582,  0.0022879 ,  0.00229021,  0.00229044])` .How come this difference? Also from this the minimum in the first case is the last entry, so would give `0.0001`, while in the second case is the first entry so it would give `0.1`.

Comment: It's negated (probably a design-decision to only have one objective-direction in GridSearchCV and co.), so i would expect you search for the maximum then. But it's a bit of work to deduce where those values come from and i'm not that familiar with the interaction of CV and scorings (there is some normalization for example in these scorers = dividing by the samples).

Answer (score 1):

sascha's answer is correct.  Here is a proof that RidgeCV does pick the right alpha.

I write a function to test whether the index of the minimum cross validated error for the alphas match the index of 0.1 in the list of alphas.

```
def test_RidgeCV(alphas):
    modelCV = RidgeCV(alphas = alphas, store_cv_values = True)
    modelCV.fit(X,y)
    modelCV.score(X,y)
    # print(modelCV.alpha_)
    CV_values =modelCV.cv_values_
    mean_error = np.min(CV_values, axis=0)
    return alphas.index(0.1) == np.argmin(mean_error)
```

Then I run through the full permutation of the list of alphas provided in the question.   No matter where we put the 0.1, its index always matches the index of the minimum error.
This is exhaustive test.  We got 24 True's.

```
alphas=[0.1, 0.01, 0.001,0.0001]

from itertools import permutations
alphas_list = list(permutations(alphas))
for i in range(len(alphas_list)):
    print(test_RidgeCV(alphas=alphas_list[i]))
```

Out:
True
True
...
True